# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Tensor'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to convert a the initializer form from `tf.Variable` to `tf.get_variable` for `Cudnn_GRU` but I keep getting this error. I have to convert because tensorflow does not allow initializing in loop/control-flow functions and only allow lambda initializers or through `tf.get_variable`

I have reduced the problem into the following minimal example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
e = tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.1, 0.1)
i = tf.constant(0)
def func():
    gru_fw = tf.contrib.cudnn_rnn.CudnnGRU(num_layers=1, num_units=75, input_size=25)
    # original line: commented out and working if not under a control flow mechanism
    # param_fw = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([gru_fw.params_size()], -0.1, 0.1), validate_shape=False)
    # converted line
    param_fw = tf.get_variable("abcd", shape=[gru_fw.params_size()],initializer=e, validate_shape=False)
    return param_fw

def func2():
    ### repeat the same thing from func1
    pass

result = tf.cond(tf.equal(i, tf.constant(0)),func,func2)
```

The traceback is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "test_run_error.py", line 16, in <module>
        result = tf.cond(tf.equal(i, tf.constant(0)),func,func2)
    File "/home/search/snetP/snet/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 316, in new_func
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/search/snetP/snet/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 1855, in cond
        orig_res_t, res_t = context_t.BuildCondBranch(true_fn)
    File "/home/search/snetP/snet/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 1725, in BuildCondBranch
        original_result = fn()
    File "test_run_error.py", line 9, in func
        param_fw = tf.get_variable("abcd", shape=[gru_fw.params_size()],initializer=e, validate_shape=False)
    File "/home/search/snetP/snet/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1203, in get_variable
        constraint=constraint)
    File "/home/search/snetP/snet/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1092, in get_variable
        constraint=constraint)
    File "/home/search/snetP/snet/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 425, in get_variable
        constraint=constraint)
    File "/home/search/snetP/snet/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 394, in _true_getter
        use_resource=use_resource, constraint=constraint)
    File "/home/search/snetP/snet/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 730, in _get_single_variable
        shape = tensor_shape.as_shape(shape)
    File "/home/search/snetP/snet/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 849, in as_shape
        return TensorShape(shape)
    File "/home/search/snetP/snet/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 455, in __init__
        self._dims = [as_dimension(d) for d in dims_iter]
    File "/home/search/snetP/snet/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 455, in <listcomp>
        self._dims = [as_dimension(d) for d in dims_iter]
    File "/home/search/snetP/snet/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 397, in as_dimension
        return Dimension(value)
    File "/home/search/snetP/snet/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 32, in __init__
        self._value = int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Tensor'
```

Comment: Could you include the full traceback resulting from running this code?

Comment: @glibdud Done and added!

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that `gru_fw.params_size()` is returning `Tensor("strided_slice_1:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)` instead of the int it's apparently supposed to return.  `tf.get_variable` won't accept a tensor as the `shape` argument.  Your `tf.Variable` code runs but it produces a variable with a shape of `<unknown>`, which would likely cause problems when you try to use it.

Unfortunately I'm not finding a lot of documentation on how to properly create and use a `CudnnGRU` object.  Are you following a tutorial from somewhere?  Also, what version of TensorFlow are you using?

Comment: The `tf.Variable` code works perfectly as the code progresses further. I'm following a project. Tensorflow version is 1.4.1 https://github.com/HKUST-KnowComp/R-Net/blob/master/func.py

Answer (score 0):

This method works for me, Try it out.

```
layers1= tf.compat.v1.layers.dense(tf_x, 10, tf.nn.relu)
output= tf.compat.v1.layers.dense(layers1, 1)
```

Comment: Can you be more clear on where this code should be incorporated. Is this replacing an existing code or is this in addition to an existing code. Also, I would recommend you read how to write a good [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)